# Scrapy returning data other than item

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have written a spider to crawl through a webpage (with all the help i got from here) and it returns the items with all the required attribute.
It returns a dictionary of the form, 
{"count": 24, "Gender": "Female ", "Age": "25-34", "Location": "Edinburgh", "Name": "abcde"}

and I want it to return only a list like :
[24, "Female", "25-34", "Edinburgh", "abcde"]

which I can then store in a file.
How can I do this ?

Edit : But I am unable to return the dictionary values. If i use 
return item.values() 
i get the error... 
Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None got unicode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding the requirement, but if you want your output file to look more like a list than a dictionary, then perhaps you should be outputting a csv file instead of a json file? The csv feed export uses the [CSVItemExporter](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#csvitemexporter) class and will produce output in the following form:

```
count,Gender,Age,Location,Name 
24,Female,25-34,Edinburgh,abcde
```

It should be possible to achieve this by running the following command:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.csv -t csv
```

If you want to produce output without the header, then you'll need to sub-class CSVItemExporter and set the `include_headers_line` parameter to False since the default value of that parameter is True.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract only the values from the dictionary and do whatever you'd like:

```
>>> d = {"count": 24, "Gender": "Female ", "Age": "25-34", "Location": "Edinburgh", "Name": "abcde"}
>>>
>>> d.values()
[24, 'Female ', '25-34', 'Edinburgh', 'abcde']
```

Comment: But I am unable to return the dictionary values.  If i use return item.values() i get the error... Spider must return Request, BaseItem or None.

Comment: well, when you get the result after the return, why not extract the values then?

Comment: scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.json -t json - this is the command i use to write multiples results together in a .json file. How do i edit this to write only the values.

Comment: the command you used is for exporting scraped data in json, and it does its job. To export the data in different format, use another exporter